# Change logged user password route always redirects to home page in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to add the Change password option for the logged user. Therefore I overwrite the default reset password option in Laravel 5.

I removed password token option and instead of email I used full_name

```
   public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [

            'full_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(
            'full_name', 'password', 'password_confirmation'
        );

        $response = $this->passwords->reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
        {
            $user->password = bcrypt($password);

            $user->save();

            $this->auth->login($user);
        });

        switch ($response)
        {
            case PasswordBroker::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return view('auth.reset');

            default:
                return redirect()->back()
                            ->withInput($request->only('full_name'))
                            ->withErrors(['full_name' => trans($response)]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getReset()
    {


        return view('auth.reset');
    }

Route::post('example/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

When I try to access this route URL, it always redirects to home page. please advice

view - reset.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('Auth\AuthController@update') }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}"> -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">fullname</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" value="{{ old('full_name') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Reset Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: you are not passing any view in `postReset`

Comment: @violator667 : i do. i have updated question with view. please check

Comment: No you don't. You have: `return redirect($this->redirectPath());` and `return redirect()->back() [...]` you only return view in your `getReset()` method which is not mentioned in your `routes.php`

Comment: @violator667 : i changed it . check updated question. but still same

Comment: are you trying to access `example/reset` with post or get method? If I'm right you should access the form via get method (I can't see any in your `routes.php`).